# Regex to search and replace text in a string

Tags: java, regex

```
String text = the property value [[some.text]] and [[value2.value]]should be replaced.
```

The values `[[some.some]]` should be replaced with some dynamic code.

```
String entryValue = entry.getValue();           

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([[\\w]])");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(entryValue);

            while(matcher.find()){

             String textToReplace = matcher.group(1);
             textToReplace = textToReplace.replace(".","");

             String resolvedValue =   "text to be replaced";
             matcher.replaceAll(resolvedValue);                 
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape `[ and ]` as these are special regex symbols:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "(\\[\\[[\\w.]*\\]\\])" );
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need two backslashes?

Comment: You don't need to escape `]` id it doesn't have opened and unescaped `[` before it.

Comment: @Pshemo: True but for readability purpose I always escape them.

Comment: The pattern ("(\\[\\[\\w\\]\\])") does not match any words in  the above string.

Comment: Agree that it makes regex more readable. I just mention it as interesting additional info so others wouldn't be surprised that `\[x]` compiles fine.

Comment: No luck. .*? does not match.

Comment: That works. Thanks for your help. Can you just give a description of that regex?

Comment: Is it possible to get only the string instead of [[]]??

Comment: Yes definitely use this regex: `"\\[\\[([\\w.]*)\\]\\]"` Working Demo:  http://ideone.com/eWudyx

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47061/discussion-between-user679526-and-anubhava)